# How to save annotation in flexpaper?

Tags: annotations, save, flexpaper

I m trying to  save annotation in flexpaper.. I tried  using this

```
marksArray = JSON.stringify($FlexPaper('documentViewer').getMarkList());

var initialMarks = JSON.parse(marksArray);

$FlexPaper('documentViewer').addMarks(initialMarks);
```

but it's not working..

In console, I tried using marks = $FlexPaper('documentViewer').getMarkList()[0];
I can see that its storing inside marks but for $FlexPaper('documentViewer').addMarks(marks) it's showing undefined.

Am I missing something? Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We 'll get the require files after downloading Annotations Web Server Package from flexpaper classic page. what I missed was <'flexpaper:annotations_handler  runat="server"/> It should be inside the script in simple_document.aspx page. And In annotations_handlers.ascx page I shifted that (onMarkCreated ,onMarkDeleted,onMarkChanged) JQuery code to flexpaper_handlers.js file. After these changes its working for me.